# How to git ignore everything apart from some select files and directories

Tags: git, gitignore, ignore

I'm having some trouble getting my `.gitignore` in just the way I want it. I've looked at previous questions on StackOverflow and I've also asked ChatGPT but I just can't get the result I want.

This is for my dotfiles config that I want to be able to easily git clone from any new machine. I have a the git repo with `nvim`, `tmux` and `alacritty` configs + other stuff that I don't want to include, so I'm trying to ignore everything apart from these directories and children within these directories.

Here is a screenshot that includes my current `.gitignore` the structure of my git repo (files with a grey colour are being ignored) and a git status to prove that they are definitely being ignored:
[image]

I want my `.gitignore` in a state that:

1. Any new file added to the `nvim` directory is added (I will keep ignoring the `lazy-lock.json`), so that I can add new plugins easily
2. ONLY the `tmux/tmux.conf` and `tmux/plugins/tpm` are NOT ignored, but the remaining directories in `tmux/plugins` ARE ignored (tpm is added in my `.gitmodules` and I want that to sync across my machines. I will install the remaining plugins using tpm)

As I said, I know there are already other questions related to this but I just can't get the exact ignore configuration I want so I need some help.

Comment: I would suggest observing a solution using git bare
https://mjones44.medium.com/storing-dotfiles-in-a-git-repository-53f765c0005d it will allow you to control on specific files you would like to commit into remote branch

Comment: I see in that article that they use `git add <something>` which might be what I resort to, I've seen that will add something even if it is in the gitignore, and I think I probably only need to add this once and then just do a submodule update whenever I need to

Comment: With that approach you don't need gitignore you specify only the files you would like to commit since you aren't prompted for changed files that aren't in the git tree

Comment: Aha I figured it out, I wasn't adding tpm as a git submodule correctly. Doing a `git submodule add` will give a warning stating "this path is in your ignored paths" or something like that, and then you do the `git submodule add` with a `-f` flag to force it to add. This is what I needed and has the results I want as everything else in the `tmux/plugins` dir is still ignored, and updating `tpm` will need to be done on each machine used `git submodule update` + other submodule commands, which I'm perfectly happy with.